# Migrating AccentColor: How to change RadioListTile and SwitchListTile colors?

Tags: flutter, themes

The new version of Flutter (from 2.5 onwards) has deprecated the accentColor property within ThemeData and now must be handled from colorScheme as a secondary color `colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith (secondary: newColorForAccent))`,

Such as I can view, it is not enough since accentColor was also used in Flutter to define the color of other widgets such as CheckBoxTile and SwitchListTile.

The ThemeData that I have in main is as follows:

```
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Color (0xFF4BD1FF),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Color (0xFFD8A21B)),
      //textTheme and others
    ),
```

How can I redefine the color of these widgets so that it can be used throughout the App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with a bit of trial and error. I leave it here in case it is useful to someone. Basically what is required is to define the themes for each component inside ThemeData. Here's an example:

```
  checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
    checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color (0xFFD8A21B))
  ),
  switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
    thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color (0xFFD8A21B)),
    trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color (0x66D8A21B)),
  ),
  radioTheme: RadioThemeData(
    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color (0xFFD8A21B))
  ),
```

Since this is part of the main, don't forget to always do a **Full Restart** after implementing. The Flutter Hot reload will not display any changes in this case.